# Using HTML parser to get contents of a particular div

Tags: python, html, sql, beautifulsoup

I want to use a HTML parser like beautiful soup (python) to get the contents of a specific div, store all data within it in my local server by running a python script that will be executed regularly on my web server by cron.

Also, I need to be able to show those contents exactly as they were shown in the webpage before on my web site.

If the contents of the div is text alone, it would be easy enough but it is a combination of text and image.
Although there are occasionally swf files, I do not wish to import them.

Let's say the div in question is called 'cont'. 
What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Best way to do this should be writing some code first, tbh. Otherwise, what you're asking for is just too broad.

Comment: After writing the question, I thought XML could be a way to do this. Do you think it's a good idea?

Comment: It is indeed possible. Off the top of my head, though, if the page being parsed is small, I don't see why a simple combination of urllib and bs4 or lxml will not suffice. You can store the image offline as well, possibly in a database, of which Python has rich resources already. :)

Comment: If it's alright, what's the URL and specific div you're trying to scrape?

Comment: oh.. I didn't know such things existed (bs4 and lxml) I will have a look at them. Thanks :) (just realized bs4 is beautifulsoup lol)

Comment: I'll try writing some generic code for this when I'm home. This is actually quite easy. You just have to set it up properly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily i have a spider which does exactly what you need to do.

```
from soup import BeautifulSoup as bs
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from hn.items import HnItem


class HnSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'hn'
    allowed_domains = []
    start_urls = ['http://news.ycombinator.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        if 'news.ycombinator.com' in response.url:
            soup = bs(response.body)
            items = [(x[0].text, x[0].get('href')) for x in
                     filter(None, [
                         x.findChildren() for x in
                         soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'title'})
                     ])]

            for item in items:
                print item
                hn_item = HnItem()
                hn_item['title'] = item[0]
                hn_item['link'] = item[1]
                try:
                    yield Request(item[1], callback=self.parse)
                except ValueError:
                    yield Request('http://news.ycombinator.com/' + item[1], callback=self.parse)

                yield hn_item
```

Refer the [Github link](https://github.com/ajkumar25/HNScrapy) to know more.